# Regression manhwa where the female lead goes back to the day of her mother's funeral

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics

It's been awhile since I've read this, so I'm not completely sure on the details. The female lead (FL) goes back in time to her mother's funeral (it might've been the day after). While her father is out to go get his other daughter to bring her back, she is working with the butler to find the documents that basically prove she is the rightful heir to the family noble title. She uses them to kick her father and half-sister out, so she doesn't have to go through the same hardships as before.

The father was very much in love with another woman and had a child with her, so he was going to bring the child back with him to give her all the luxuries that belong to the female lead. Through the years, before the FL's mother's death, he had been telling her about all the stuff she was going to get when the time would come. Because of this, the half-sister believed she would be getting everything she ever wanted. And in the FL's first life, she did get everything that was supposed to be hers.

I don't remember how exactly she lived her first life, but she was neglected, I believe. (I'm sorry if this is a bit all over the place; I'm not very good with wording and my memory isn't the best.)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Comment: Hi, thank you. I apologize for the late response. I believe her hair is red or black. My memory is a bit hazy, I'm sorry...

Comment: @LogicDictates I apologize again, I had a family thing and I didn't receive a notification. Do you possibly have any idea of what the title is? I really appreciate any answer you might have. As you can see, this is my first time on this site so I really don't know much. I'm sorry if I say something wrong.

Comment: I did search for this, but didn't find a matching story. I'll have another look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this ***[I Don't Want to Be Loved](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/i-dont-want-to-be-loved-novel)***...?

> Rihannan Alessin, a queen rotting in prison. Despaired and without hope, she drank poison and died. But… unbeknownst to her, the deity gave her a second chance at life. She was twelve again. And this time, she would live life differently. Six years later, she chooses to become Arundell’s queen… “If you’re asking me to step down from the marriage proposal, I can’t.” “Marry me and let us divorce after a year.” And this time, the time limit of their marriage would last a year. A husband she knew who was different than before… she tried not to love him again, but each time, her heart kept shaking.
>
> [image: Promotional art for "I Don't Want to Be Loved".]

The protagonist, Lianan Cheska, is a noble of royal blood. I think her hair is supposed to be white or silver, but it has a bluish tint in many panels and in the promotional art.

Her father, Count Regan Aleshin, was a low-ranking noble whose wealth and status were elevated when he married her mother, Anastasia Prebius. He never loved her mother though, and had an affair that produced an illegitimate daughter and younger half-sister to Lianan; a red-haired girl named Leticia, who was raised by her own mother away from the mansion Lianan grew up in.

Some time after that, when Lianan was 12, her mother died of illness, and the day after her funeral, Lianan's father brought Leticia to the mansion to live with them.

Years later, Lianan ultimately wound up in prison, where she was paid a visit by Leticia, who came to gloat at her predicament. She subsequently took her own life, using poison given to her by her half-brother.

She then wakes up in bed as her 12-year-old self, the day after her mother's funeral. Knowing that her father will bring Leticia to the mansion later that day, she sends for her father's lawyer, and with her now adult-level knowledge and intellect, forces him to draft legal documents enabling her to name her uncle as her new guardian, and kick her father and Leticia out of the mansion.

Comment: I believe this is it. I apologize for getting the hair color wrong, I suppose I got the FL and illegitimate child mixed up.